# Facing ProcessException issue in android studio. java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Facing issue while running my app.Getting error as mentioned below:

```
Execution failed for task ':android-readerplus:dexDevDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Logcat:**

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
:android-readerplus:newRelicDeinstrumentTask
[newrelic.info] Deinstrumenting...
Error:Execution failed for task ':android-readerplus:dexDevDebug'.
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program      Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  Information:BUILD FAILED
  Information:Total time: 53.666 secs
  Information:1 error
```

**Gradle Console:**

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: string \u0027newtext\u0027 has no default translation.","position":{},"original":"warning: string \u0027newtext\u0027 has no default translation."}

   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
  Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
  The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
  :android-readerplus:newRelicDeinstrumentTask
  [newrelic.info] Deinstrumenting...


   Error:Execution failed for task ':android-readerplus:dexDevDebug'.com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
   Information:BUILD FAILED
   Information:Total time: 53.666 secs
   Information:1 error
```

**build.gradle:**

```
  android {
        signingConfigs {
          debug {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
def versionNumber = '1.28'
def propertiesFile = new File(project.rootDir, 'version.properties')
if (propertiesFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties properties = new Properties()

    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile))

    def fileVersionNumber = properties['version_number']
    def fileVersionSequence = properties['version_sequence'].toInteger()

    if(!versionNumber.equals(fileVersionNumber)) {
        fileVersionSequence = 0
        properties['version_number'] = versionNumber
    }

    fileVersionSequence++

    properties['version_sequence'] = fileVersionSequence.toString()
    properties.store(propertiesFile.newWriter(), null)

    def DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat('000');
    def name = versionNumber + '.' + numberFormat.format(fileVersionSequence)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName name
        applicationId "com.pearson.android.readerplus"
        testApplicationId "com.pearson.android.readerplus.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}


repositories {
      flatDir {
         dirs 'libs'
      }
   }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

 dependencies {
   androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
     exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger', module: 'dagger'
     exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
     exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'

    }
     androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
       exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger', module: 'dagger'
    exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'

    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
     compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile(name: 'gutenberg-sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.244.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/crashlytics-1.1.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/sugar-1.3.jar')
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

   }
```

No idea why it is caused.I checked with gradle files,cleaning and rebuilding the project.i have gone through may stackoverflow questions similar to this problem.But nothing worked out.Help me out in this, guys!

Comment: Please post whole logcat.! Actually problem statements will be above this  'Execution failed for task ...' statement..!!

Comment: Put your gradle file @Karthika

Comment: @Karthika : What is your machine RAM ..??

Comment: @Mamata Gelanee 4GB RAM.

Comment: Since yesterday i am facing this issue.Before that i was able to run the app without any problem

Answer (score 0):

Support v7 with support v4 makes conflict, and also you have added two different versions of appcompat, try with this dependencies

```
dependencies {
     androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
     exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger', module: 'dagger'
     exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
     exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'

    }
     androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
       exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger', module: 'dagger'
    exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
}
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', dir: 'libs')
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
     compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
     compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile(name: 'gutenberg-sdk-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.244.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/crashlytics-1.1.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/sugar-1.3.jar')
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Open 'studio.exe.vmoptions' from your path like this :**

android-studio-installation-location\android-studio\bin

**2. Change this content :**

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

**3. Restart Android studio.**

Hope it will help.